# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que al hacer click en el botón Next del carrusel, este se agrande?

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-carousel

¡Hola!
Estoy usando Bootstrap para crear un slider. El problema está en que cuando hago click en el botón para pasar de slide, el carrusel se hace un poco más grande y luego vuelve al tamaño original. No quiero que eso suceda, quiero que el slider se mantenga del mismo tamaño siempre, aún cambiando de imagen. Les dejo mi código por acá:

```html
<!--Para stackOverflow-->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--End for stackOverflow-->
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carrusel" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="../images/comercios/abba/logo.png" alt="First slide">
    </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="../images/comercios/chechomedrano/logo.png" alt="Second slide">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="../images/comercios/cybertom/logo.png" alt="Third slide">
  </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bi bi-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bi bi-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: fija las dimensiones de los elementos a mostrar, de modo que sean iguales para todos. Cuando rroten no habra problemas

Answer (score 1):

Primero tienes que saber que saber que los botones de flecha no se aumentan si no cambian de color (de gris a blanco) y lo hacen al pasar el ratón sobre ellas de este modo se parece que se agranden, para evitar esto puedes editar el color del elemento (la flecha) al pasar el ratón al cual necesitas aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como lo puedes hacer con CSS usando las propiedades `:hover, :focus y :active` que significa en ingles por un ratón encima y activo:

Primero tienes que identificar la flecha lo puedes obtener usando el inspeccionador de elemento (en la mayoría de los navegadores es tecla F12 o click derecho sobre el elemento y luego selecciona inspeccionar elemento o algo parecido) ahí veras el class de la flecha que es `carousel-control-next` y `carousel-control-prev`

Y luego vamos a ingresar los valores en la etiqueta  como se ve en el código:

```html
<!--Para stackOverflow-->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--End for stackOverflow-->
<style>
  .carousel-control-next:focus, .carousel-control-next:hover, .carousel-control-prev:focus, .carousel-control-prev:hover, .carousel-control-next:active, .carousel-control-prev:active {
color: #fff; /* Aquí escribieras el color de la flecha al pasar el ratón */
outline: 0;
opacity: .5; /* Aquí escribieras la opacidad de la flecha al pasar el ratón lo puse en 0.5 en lugar de 0.9*/
  }
  </style>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carrusel" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/05/19/73/39/360_F_519733913_rsuvNKC76m4RWgKwrQz8sOteM8HpnAT5.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://e0.pxfuel.com/wallpapers/103/348/desktop-wallpaper-plain-black.jpg" alt="Second slide">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/90/72/80/907280526f902884ceae47fffefb8289.jpg" alt="Third slide">
  </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bi bi-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bi bi-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Nota: Añadí imágenes al slider para ver mejor los efectos y por esto es mejor ver el código en pantalla completa